# Text countdown with progress bar in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-progressbar

Is there any way to have a progressbar with a countdown timer in action bar?
I am able to enable progress bar in action bar by

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(...);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

I am able to set a countdown timer(TextView) in the MenuItem by

```
private void startTimer(long duration, long interval) {

    timer = new CountDownTimer(duration, interval) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //Kills current Activity        
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisecondsLeft) {
            int secondsLeft = (int) Math.round((millisecondsLeft / (double) 1000));
            MenuItem timerItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.timer_item);//Where mMenu is the menu inflated
            timerItem.setTitle(secondsLeft+"");

        }
    };

    timer.start();
}
```

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:compatibility="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/timer_item"
    name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    compatibility:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"/>

</menu>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to integrate these two an make a progress bar with countdown timer in it(on action bar) ??

Comment: create your custom actionbar , you will be able to add any view to it because it will be an xml layout like the activity ...so you will be able to inser anything

Comment: got it, but that's a workaround only if there is no other possible way with the default action bar. Currently I am searching for possible ways with default action bar.